# Program is working on code block but not in hacker rank

Tags: c, gcc

This piece of code works returns correct output in codeblock but not on hacker rank. I am not getting the issue?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num,i;
    long long unsigned int *num_alloc, FinalSum = 0;
    num_alloc=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*num);
    scanf("%d",&num);
    for ( i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        scanf("%llu",&num_alloc[num]);
        FinalSum =FinalSum + num_alloc[num];
    }
    printf("%llu",FinalSum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tell me, what is the value of `num` when you use it to `malloc`?

Comment: Ummm, I don't know, but after talking to the duck (see: [**How to debug small programs**](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)), I still can't answer -- but I know that can't be right...

Comment: Enable all warnings and debug info, with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. You'll get several warnings. Improve your code to get none. Read the documentation of [scanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) -it returns an item count that you should use- and of [malloc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) -it can fail- ... then **use the debugger `gdb`**

Comment: What is `long long unsigned int`? I don't know if that's 64 bit or 32 bit. I think you want `int` since you are casting to `int`

Comment: @Barmak Shernirani: `long long unsigned int` is legal, but could be written `unsigned long long`. It is at least 64 bits, but you should not care if it is bigger (and I know no C implementation where that happens). You could also use `uint64_t` from `<stdint.h>`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I forgot that's legal. But the asker has `num_alloc=malloc(sizeof(int)*num)` which allocates half of what is required for `long long` since `int` is usually 4 bytes.

Comment: Wot no `free` ?

Comment: @Bathsheba - Don't be silly. Haxor's don't `free`

Comment: The next thing is to ask yourself "now... why do I *need* to allocate memory"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A number of things are jumping out at me about your code. You are allocating memory for `num` integers, when `num` is uninitialized. It is given an undefined trash value. See [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You must put your scanf statement before your malloc, because as it stands right now your code does not make sense.

```
for ( i=0;i<num;i++)
{
    scanf("%llu",&num_alloc[num]);
    FinalSum =FinalSum + num_alloc[num];
}
```

For each loop iteration, you are accessing the `num`th element of your array. This is not possible as `num_alloc` should be an array of `num` ints, and array indexes in C start at 0. But what I'm pretty sure what you meant to do is this. With your code, you would have been assigning the same value over and over again.

```
for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    scanf("%llu", &num_alloc[i]);
    FinalSum += num_alloc[i];
}
```

You must also `free()` any memory you allocate on the heap with `malloc()`.

```
free(num_alloc);
```

Comment: I would add that in that case `free`ing is not entirely necessary ( end of program, resource are reclaimed by the operating system ), but is considered a good practice.

Answer (score 4):

let's walk through your code:

1. `malloc(sizeof(int) * num)`, what is the value of `num` ?
2. `scanf("%d",num)`, check the return value of `scanf` ( number of element successfully parsed by `scanf` )
3. `for( i = 0 ; i < num; i++ )`, loop with `i` from `0` to `num`
4. `scanf("%llu",&num_alloc[num])`, read number and store it in `num_alloc[num]` ( indices of array in C start from `0` )
5. `FinalSum = FinalSum + num_alloc[num]`, add `num_alloc[num]` to `FinalSum` ( see #4 )
6. end loop

I provided some advice to fix your code. But additionally do you need to store each values that are read until the end of the program ?

Also, 'malloc' is a function of 'stdlib.h' and you didn't include that header file.

Comment: Prefer `for( int i = 0 ; i < num; i++ )`?

Comment: @Bathsheba I was merely copying the line of the source code, not rewriting the code from the question

Answer (score 3):

Before allocating memory for `num_alloc`, you must initialize the `num` variable. If not, memory for `num_alloc` will be allocated with a trash size, so you've got [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).